# ScrollView or ListView for a color changer like Aviary's

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-background

I have an app where I am trying to implement a color picker. Right now I have a Horizontal ScrollView with a LinearLayout. Inside the LinearLayout are buttons for the corresponding colors. While this does work I would like to have it so is acts more like a slider where whichever color is above the indicator would be the set color. It would be like the Text color selector in the Aviary photo app. Would this be better accomplished with just a ListView or maybe a ViewPager?

Here is a screenshot of the Aviary color slider I would like to emulate as far as the basic function goes.

[image]

xml code for ScrollView:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/edit_dateText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/color_button_green"
            android:background="@drawable/color_green"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:id="@+id/color_button_blue"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/color_blue"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:id="@+id/color_button_red"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/color_red"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:id="@+id/color_button_orange"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/color_orange"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

        .........................................
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

onCreateView override and custom onCLickListener:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment, parent, false);

    mGreenColorButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.color_button_green);
    mGreenColorButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    mBlueColorButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.color_button_blue);
    mBlueColorButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    mRedColorButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.color_button_red);
    mRedColorButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    mOrangeColorButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.color_button_orange);
    mOrangeColorButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    mGrayColorButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.color_button_gray);
    mGrayColorButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    mPurpleColorButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.color_button_purple);
    mPurpleColorButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    return v;
}
private final class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.color_button_green:
                activeEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#36D85C"));
            break;
            case R.id.color_button_blue:
                activeEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0C44E5"));
                break;
            case R.id.color_button_red:
                activeEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E22D3A"));
                break;
            case R.id.color_button_orange:
                activeEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F39D15"));
                break;
            case R.id.color_button_gray:
                activeEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#555555"));
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post code, and say wats your problem.

Comment: The code I have works fine. My question is mostly what route to go to accomplish my new goal. I want to select the buttons based on the scroll position instead of touching the buttons. Is this even possible in a ScrollView?

Comment: I would also like to avoid individually inflating each button.

Comment: @pdfj I also have similar problem. Want to create a kind of colour slider/colour carousel which changes colour of background depending on which colour is below indicator. Have you found a solution?